# Query Firebase dynamic link information

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

When trying to query Google Firebase dynamic link stats I am getting an empty object.

I've got 5 dynamic links in the firebase console which were created via the console. Using the following code I am able to get a token.  I used the GCP->IAM->Service Accounts to create a new account and pull down the JSON file.  I've ensured the project_id matches the one in firebase.

```
link = "my_dynamic_link_short_name"
scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase"]
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("key.json", scopes=scopes)
url_base = "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/SHORT_DYNAMIC_LINK/linkStats?durationDays=1"

encoded_link = urllib.parse.quote(link, safe='')
url = url_base.replace('SHORT_DYNAMIC_LINK', encoded_link)

request = Request()
credentials.refresh(request)
access_token = credentials.token
HEADER = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token}
response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADER)
print(response.json())
```

Both of the above requests return a 200 but no data returned.

The GCP service account I am using has the following roles:

- Firebase Admin
- Firebase Admin SDK Administrator Service Agent
- Service Account Token Creator

I've given it full owner to test and it didn't resolve issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FDL Analytics REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics#rest_api) returns an empty object `{}` if the short link doesn't have analytics data on the specified date range. If you have existing short links in the FDL dashboard that has click data, you can use it to validate if the response from the API matches the data displayed on the dashboard.

If you're still having issues, I suggest filing a ticket https://firebase.google.com/support

Edit: To add, Firebase Dynamic Links click data are aggregated daily and should be updated the next day. For newly created links, give it a day or two for the click data to be updated. This applies on both click data from the API and the one displayed on the dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It gave me just enough of a nudge to help me figure it out.  My "durationDays" was set at 1 day and we don't typically see dynamic link data for 2-3 days after.  If you can add this to your answer I'll select and up vote.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for adding this. I think 2-3 days is required for newly created links, but click data should be updated daily - similar to Google Analytics for Firebase.